# Subquery returned more than 1 value while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
    @Ecode NVARCHAR(50), 
    @startdate DATETIME, 
    @enddate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 120);
    DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 120);
    SELECT  e.Ecode
        ,   CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date
        ,   e.Ename
        ,   COUNT(q.Ecode) CntEcode
        ,   (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM Transaction_tbl
                WHERE dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''
                    AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
                    AND DelEcode = @Ecode
                GROUP BY CAST(dtime AS DATE)
            )
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e
    JOIN Transaction_tbl q ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode
    WHERE q.Ecode = @Ecode
        AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''
        AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
    GROUP BY
        e.Ecode
    ,   e.Ename
    ,   CAST(q.dtime AS DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS DATE)
END
```

while executing this query am getting error like this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: data-type of dtime is datetime

Answer (score 0):

In your query you have :

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Transaction_tbl
    WHERE dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''
        AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
        AND DelEcode = @Ecode
    GROUP BY CAST(dtime AS DATE)
)
```

as a column. The above because of the GROUP BY will return more than one rows for each row of your select. This is not posible in SQL.